# Kalman filter innovation residual inversion

Tags: math, matrix-inverse, kalman-filter

I'm trying to implement a Kalman filter in a computationally efficient way. The main issue is the inversion of the innovation residual:

```
  S=HPH^t+R

  K=PH^t*inv(S)
```

My question is, can one assume that the S matrix in positive definite? This would make inverting it more computationally efficient....

Comment: perhaps I should move this to the math community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, S is symmetric positive definite** as mentioned here, and also how it can be automatically recognized:

- [Matrix Expressions and BLAS/LAPACK; SciPy 2013 Presentation](http://youtu.be/nVt24G_2VC0?t=16m36s)

I find that presentation fascinating!

---

**EDIT:** I have done a little research and it turns out one has to be very careful when implementing the Kalman-Filter in order to retain the symmetric positive definiteness. Keywords: "stabilized Kalman filter" and "Josepf form". See for example [Linear-Optimal Estimation for Discrete-Time Systems, page 7](http://www.princeton.edu/~stengel/MAE546Lecture18.pdf) or [Understanding and Applying Kalman Filtering, page 28](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/integrated3/kleeman_kalman_basics.pdf).

To address [bits_international's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500802/kalman-filter-innovation-residual-inversion#comment37955991_24514412), see [Under what circumstance will a covariance matrix be positive semi-definite rather than positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54926/9010) or page 7 in *Understanding and Applying Kalman Filtering*.  In short, it is positive definite unless there is a linear
dependence among the components.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point be toward a proof (however complicated)?

Comment: as a covariance matrix S is positive-semidefinite, I am not sure if this is definite

Comment: @staple I am glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to reduce the cost of inverting `S` is to use serial updates.  In a nutshell:  Predict, then repeat the update step for each *row* of `H`.  In this case, `HPH'`, `R`, and therefore `S` are all scalar, so inverting `S` is trivial.  If `R` is diagonal (as is often the case) this doesn't require any extra work.  If there are off-diagonal terms, you can orthogonalize your measurements.  Most of the effort there can be pre-computed.

Several square root KF formulations rely on serial updates, so look at those for more ideas.